# Why am I not getting the values ​I want with scipy.optimize. (linear programming problems)

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

b_ub = [74, 40, 36]
b_eq = [20, 45, 30]
A = np.array([[7, 3, 6], [4, 8, 2], [1, 5, 9]])
m, n = A.shape
c = list(np.reshape(A, n * m))  # Convert matrix A to list c.
A_ub = np.zeros([m, m * n])
for i in np.arange(0, m,
                   1):  # Filling in the matrix of conditions-inequalities.
    for j in np.arange(0, n * m, 1):
        if i * n <= j <= n + i * n - 1:
            A_ub[i, j] = 1
A_eq = np.zeros([m, m * n])
for i in np.arange(0, m, 1):  # Filling in the matrix of conditions-equalities
    k = 0
    for j in np.arange(0, n * m, 1):
        if j == k * n + i:
            A_eq[i, j] = 1
            k = k + 1
print(linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq))
```

I'm getting this

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: Please add expected and actual output as text, not as images of text.

Comment: What you see is a solution from an interior-point based solver (which seems to be the default one). It's a (a-priori parameterized) approximation and does not deliver a basic feasible solution in general. Solutions can look like there is some small rounding needed. Using a simplex-based solver as shown in the answer below, you can obtain your expected solution which, as always with simplex, is a basic feasible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is due to the default solver. Swapping the solver gave the solution you looked for. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) and evaluate the tradeoffs of using each solver to determine what you want to use.

```
print(linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, method='highs-ds'))

           con: array([0., 0., 0.])
 crossover_nit: 0
           fun: 215.0
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
           nit: 3
         slack: array([29., 10., 16.])
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 0., 45.,  0.,  0.,  0., 30., 20.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and quick answer, this forum works great. Maybe I did not understand the problem and asked a simple question, but sometimes there is no time, sorry.

Comment: No worries at all. The default parameters for these libraries can cause lots of confusion!